# for each row get frequency of the most frequent value

Tags: python, pandas, frequency

I have a dataframe that lookS like this:

```
var1  var2   var3  var4
a      a      a    b
c      c      b    d
e      e      f    g 
g      a      a    z
g      a      a    g
w      w      w    w
```

what I want to do is to identify the most frequent value for each row and count the number of times it appears, in this case I'd get

```
var1  var2   var3  var4  frq
a      a      a    b      3
c      c      b    d      2
e      e      f    g      2
g      a      a    z      2
g      a      a    g      2
w      w      w    w      4
```

I was thinking to use something like pd.get_dummies but there would be too many dummies as each var1, var2 etc may assume quite a few different values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to apply with axis=1:

```
df['frq'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().iloc[0], axis=1)
```

Or use `stack` and `groupby`:

```
df['frq'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().max(level=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `pd.value_counts` on the transposed dataframe together with the `max()` function:

```
df["frq"] = df.T.apply(pd.value_counts).max()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) here. One thing to note is `mode` finds if there are multiples values.

From [pandas-doc `df.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html)

> The mode of a set of values is the value that appears most often. It can be multiple values.

```
df['frq'] = df.eq(df.mode(axis=1)[0], axis=0).sum(1)

 var1 var2 var3 var4  frq
0    a    a    a    b    3
1    c    c    b    d    2
2    e    e    f    g    2
3    g    a    a    z    2
4    g    a    a    g    2
5    w    w    w    w    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample. I used value_counts and applied it to all rows. I got the count of all variable and then I just choose the maximum value to get the exact result your looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': ["a","c","e","g","g","w"],
                   'var2': ["a","c","e","a","a","w"],
                   'var3': ["a","b","f","a","a","w"],
                   'var4': ["b","d","g","z","g","w"]})

frequency = df.apply(pd.value_counts, axis=1).max(axis=1)

df["frq"] = frequency

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try

```
from scipy import stats
stats.mode(df.values.T)[1]
Out[143]: array([[3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4]])
#df["frq"] =  stats.mode(df.values.T)[1][0]
```